# Return top % of results in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've a graph of students and the various books that they've read. I want to find out the top 10% of students who've read the most books. How can I do that? I've tried the following cypher syntax:

```
MATCH (s:Student)-[:READ]->(b:Book)
WITH s, COUNT(b) AS no_of_books
WHERE no_of_books > percentileCont(no_of_books, 0.9)
RETURN s.Name, no_of_books
```

The error 'invalid use of aggregating function' is returned. It seems that trying to use two aggregating functions on top of each other is an issue here. How can I tweak my syntax to make it work?

I'll be happy to use the LIMIT function instead if it can work with percentages as well.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question (again), in case someone else is looking up the same issue

```
MATCH (s:Student)-[:READ]->(b:Book)
WITH s, COUNT(b) AS no_of_books
ORDER BY no_of_books DESC
WITH COLLECT ({Student_Name: s.Name, No_of_Books: no_of_books}) AS books_per_stu
WITH books_per_stu, toInteger(size(books_per_stu)/100) AS percentile
UNWIND book_per_stu[0..percentile] AS top_stu
RETURN top_stu
```

Seems like, surprisingly, there's no straightforward way to do this, like my pseudo-code in my first post. The above syntax will return the results as a list of dictionaries rather than in a tabular format. I still welcome any answer that's simpler than mine.